nodetool gossipinfo versus nodetool status
When I shut a Cassandra 4.1.4 node down, its status on another node gets reflected by "nodetool gossipinfo" STATUS_WITH_PORT as forced down.  And "nodetool status" concurs that the node is down.
When instead I isolate that Cassandra node, using Chaos Mesh, "nodetool status" (on another node) after a short while reports the node as down, but "nodetool gossipinfo" keeps reporting the status as NORMAL in STATUS_WITH_PORT.  Supposedly, the status in "nodetool status" is reporting Gossip status.  So, why do the two commands contradict each other?
Something similar happens when isolating a DC.
Here's a variant of the experiment that isolates a single Cassandra node:
apiVersion: chaos-mesh.org/v1alpha1
kind: NetworkChaos
metadata:
  name: isolate-a-pod
spec:
  action: partition
  duration: 5m
  mode: all
  selector:
    namespaces:
      - default
    labelSelectors:
      whichPod: "pod-to-isolate"
  direction: both


Without going into too much detail, the basic reason this typically happens is because gossip is a background protocol and has a periodic cycle, so information about node isolation may take longer to propagate compared to the failure detection mechanism of nodetool.
When you use something like 'nodetool status' it has a more aggressive failure detection mechanism built into the tool so it reports faster.
Better yet, you can use 'nodetool describecluster' which will pull metadata from each node individually, so it's even more reliable for reporting the status of a node and should quickly mark the node as unreachable once isolated.

The main reason that "nodetool gossipinfo" was of interest to me is that it reflected what is available in system_views.gossip_info , which can be accessed by an ordinary DB client (as authorized).  I don't see an analogue of describecluster anywhere.  Session metadata is useful only w.r.t. the connected DC, so it's potentially useful but requires more overhead.
